# Эмуляция ввода с клавиатуры senkey не успевает обрабатываться и приходится делать задерку командой sleep

Tags: синхронизация

При эмуляции ввода с клавиатуры  в Autoit командой sendkey когда программа начинает выполняется,  то часть команд send key не успевает исполнится, а следующие команды уже выпололняются. Для решения проблемы применен sleep ().
Как сделать так чтобы не приходилось задерживать исполнение  программы командой sleep () ,в ожидании пока исполнится sendkey.
Sendkeydelay SendkeyDowndelay установлен на ноль
Буду очень благодарен за помощь
Поиск в интернете результатов не дал

Comment: Вы уже исключили проблему в приложении, которое обрабатывает нажатия клавиш?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я не совсем понял вопрос - но именно SendKeyDelay устанавливает задержку перед исполнением SendKey. Попробуйте выставить значение ~100мс.